# The function "add()" expects parameters like: "add(Integer>, Object[], int)"

Tags: arraylist, processing

I'm trying to add ArrayLists of integers into an ArrayList within a class. Unfortunately, I get the error message `The function "add()" expects parameters like: "add(Integer>, Object[],  int)"`. What could be the reason?

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
setup(){
  for (int i=0; i<numRowsFirst; i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numArray1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numArray2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numArray3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numArray4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j=0; j < numRowsSecond; j++) {
      if (firstTable.getString(i, 1).equals(secondTable.getString(j, 1))) {
        numArray1.add(secondTable.getInt(j, 4));
        numArray2.add(secondTable.getInt(j, 5));
        numArray3.add(secondTable.getInt(j, 6));
        numArray4.add(secondTable.getInt(j, 7));
      }
      countries.add(new Country(numArray1, numArray2, numArray3, numArray4));
    }
  }
}


class myClass {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bigArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  ArrayList<Integer> numArray1, numArray2, numArray3, numArray4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  myClass(ArrayList<Integer> numArray1, ArrayList<Integer> numArray2, ArrayList<Integer> numArray3, ArrayList<Integer> numArray4) {
    this.flowNumArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    flowNumArray.add(numArray1, numArray2, numArray3, numArray4);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add function expects only one element to add, not four at the same time. Instead of

```
flowNumArray.add(numArray1, numArray2, numArray3, numArray4);
```

write

```
flowNumArray.add(numArray1);
flowNumArray.add(numArray1);
flowNumArray.add(numArray1);
flowNumArray.add(numArray1);
```

With this, the problem should be solved.